# flink sql window api

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I tried to use flink sql window api:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/table_api.html#group-windows

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);

// ingest a DataStream from an external source
DataStream<Tuple3<Long, String, Integer>> ds = env.addSource(...);
// register the DataStream as table "Orders"
tableEnv.registerDataStream("Orders", ds, "user, product, amount");

// compute SUM(amount) per day (in event-time)
Table result1 = tableEnv.sql(
  "SELECT user, " +
  "  TUMBLE_START(rowtime(), INTERVAL '1' DAY) as wStart,  " +
  "  SUM(amount) FROM Orders " + 
  "GROUP BY TUMBLE(rowtime(), INTERVAL '1' DAY), user");
```

show the error:

> No match found for function signature rowtime()

Please give me a more detail example about flink-sql-window api with rowtime.Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the docs are a bit out of sync, but the community is working on it in a separate branch. Flink 1.3 introduces so called "time attributes" in order to access, express, and work with time more explicitly in the future.

You can find more information in the [current documentation draft](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/tableDocs/docs/dev/table/streaming.md). Some examples how to use the time attributes in a table program can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-libraries/flink-table/src/test/scala/org/apache/flink/table/runtime/datastream/TimeAttributesITCase.scala#L248).